# When a programming language claims to be more type safe than haskell what does that even mean?

Tags: haskell

I've heard people complaining about haskell's type system having holes and that agda and ocaml/coq are better. What are the limitations of Haskell's type system? Are there differences between the scope of strongly typed functional languages?

Comment: Google "type systems" - read wikipedia page describing various type system - navigate to the various links which lead to published papers on different type system - read all of those papers. Haskell has a specific type of type system and it is obvious when it is compared with other type systems people will find "holes" in it

Comment: I don't think anyone claims either of these languages are _better_ than the others. They all have different strengths and tradeoffs.

Comment: I think this question should be edited to be a little more direct and specific and resubmitted. It's easy enough to make it into a fairly good question, though I agree it's missing the SO format as it stands.

Comment: And I guess see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependent-type

Comment: In Haskell, unlike Agda and Coq, a list of 3 elements has the same type as a list of 333 elements.

Comment: @SK-logic A homogenous tuple can be seen as an example of fixed-size list, so I think that's just a mismatch of concepts.

Comment: A better example might be something like `Sorted` where it's possible to write an Agda `Sorted` that cannot be constructed unless the elements are sorted, while the similar construction in Haskell depends upon trusting the library implementer. This could probably be done using Haskell rather weak dependent types, but it's definitely more of a real dependently typed thing.